# How to return native app from google map in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I am opening google map from native app by below code now i want to return from google map to ios native app.How can i do this. Thanks in advance.

```
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
 NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=28.458125,77.033833&daddr=18.407000,73.506300&directionsmode=driving&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=lavasa"];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) section about the URL scheme there is an example of how the callbackl should work.

> - `x-source` The name of the application sending the x-callback request.
>     Short names are preferred.
> - `x-success` — The URL to call when complete.
>     Often this will be a URL scheme for your own app, allowing users to
>     return to the original application.

For example:

```
comgooglemaps-x-callback://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14
   &x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true
   &x-source=SourceApp
```

Here you see the `x-success` property, which should be set to your app URL scheme and the `x-source` is the name of your app as presented in Google Maps app return to app bar.

Comment: Thanks, can you write one dummy URL of lat long and app name. that can work

Comment: Just replace the `sourceapp` with you apps details, it is not that difficult.  Since I have no access to your App so I can't make the example any more clear that it is now. Since my example already includes a dummy URL.

Comment: i have used this url==comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=28.458125,77.033833&daddr=18.407000,73.506300&directionsmode=driving&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=lavasa but no cancel button is been shown in google map

Comment: because `sourceapp://?resume` is not your apps URL scheme. Google maps app check whether it can open the `x-success` url.

Comment: thanks alot, i put the url scheme in plist. everything works fine now

Comment: is that possible to return from apple calendar app?